# Group by a column and add rows to a dataframe with previous row contents

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of product information and am looking to add a "summary" row after each product. As an example table:

| Product Name | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  |  |  |
| A |  |  |  |  |
| B |  |  |  |  |
| C |  |  |  |  |
| C |  |  |  |  |

In this example table, after every "group" of products, I want to create a summary row. So in the above table, I would insert a row after the last A product, after the last B product, and again after the last C product. This row would contain the info from the final row in that group.

I've tried using the groupby method to group by product code but haven't had much luck. I have also tried to insert a new row looping through the dataframe in combination with .iloc to pass in the index of the final row of each product but have found it difficult.

Any help on how to approach this is appreciated, thank you.

Edited example:

| Product Name | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 7 | 8 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| **A** | **3** | **3** | **2** | **5** |
| B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| **B** | **1** | **1** | **1** | **4** |
| C | 7 | 8 | 4 | 2 |
| **C** | **7** | **8** | **4** | **2** |

The final rows of A, B, and C (in bold) are inserted as duplicated of the most recent row of that product code.

Comment: What should the "Product Name" column contain in the added rows?

Comment: It should be the same as the final row for that product, so after group A, the new row would have the same product name, again A.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying you want to duplicate the final row of each product, but that doesn't make sense.  Don't you want to sum up the other columns or something?

Comment: I see. Can you please provide an "actual" example input and the corresponding desired output?

Comment: Thanks for the comments from both of you. I do want to do some summing of the columns but I'm pretty confident on that, all I'm really struggling with is the duplication after each group of products. After that I can actually modify that summary row myself.

An actual example has been edited into the OP which hopefully helps.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [**`pandas.groupby.tail()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) inside `pandas.concat` for vertical stacking. And since this method preserves original index, sort the index afterwards:

```py
final_df = pd.concat(
    [original_df, 
     original_df.groupby('Product Name').tail(1)]
).sort_index()
```